# Exit php script based on the response from javascript confirm

Tags: javascript, php

I am taking the values from html form and doing some manipulations in php and updating the record of a mysql table. Before updating, i am asking the user to "confirm" using javascript. If the user press "Cancel" i don't want the record to be updated.

I have tried the following,

```
... some php code here
<script type=text/javascript>
    var to_disp = <?php echo json_encode($u_fields);?>;
    var r = confirm("Updating the fields >> " + to_disp.join());
    if (r != true){
        window.location.href = some-url;
    }
</script>

...updating the record here
```

Note: This works fine in windows. But, when moved to linux, this isn't working the page is re-directed to the mentioned url but the record is also getting updated.

Comment: You're basically doing "here, fly to China, ask the person if they want to do something, and while you're flying over there, I'll just keep on trucking with the rest of the code". What you want is not possible without fundamentally restructuring your code.

Comment: I wonder, how it is working in windows.

Comment: You should rather use ajax.

Comment: I just want to confirm from the user on what fields he is updating, I achieved this by calling a javascript function onclick(while submitting) and getting the confirmation from the user and only submitting the form on "OK" and exiting on "Cancel". Thanks anyways..

Answer (score 2):

PHP code is run server-side, Javascript client side.

For example: Create a client side form with a submit button "Confirm". Send this to the client first, then for the action of this form create a php code file which will then update/not update the record.